# CodeSearchNet could not download the database

Tags: amazon-s3

github project https://github.com/github/CodeSearchNet, unable to Download Data from S3

When I try to access
https://s3.amazonaws.com/code-search-net/CodeSearchNet/v2/java.zip
I get the following error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>T24TH6PDCYJ4MH1S</RequestId>
<HostId>D643qny/TdSa0w/ZpgUf8GxL+S8doxkB3bw70XlhBvJ04JdSdkjmr+ghNsM5jMIZakIRb9eh0Ko=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Is the resource invalid?
What else do I use to get this dataset？

Answer (score 1):

The CodeSearchNet dataset S3 bucket was taken offline when the [project was archived](https://github.com/github/CodeSearchNet#the-codesearchnet-challenge-has-been-concluded), but it can now be downloaded from HuggingFace with the following command:

```
ds = load_dataset("code_search_net", "python")
```

See here for discussion on this resolution as well as some links to other sources for it higher up the thread: https://huggingface.co/datasets/code_search_net/discussions/3#645cb625f1e3b219cb07b603